# Finding the matrix form of a linear operator with a non canonical vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given a vector space $V =\{a\cos(t) + b\sin(t) + ct\sin(t)\}$ with $a,b,c$ all real, a basis $B = \{cos(t),sin(t),t\sin(t)\}$ and a Linear operator $Lf(t) = f''(t)$, how would I write ${\lbrack L\rbrack}_{BB}$?

I attempted it and got \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 2t \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -t 
\end{bmatrix}

however my professor shows the matrix representation as being

\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}

and so I am unsure as to why the $t$ disappeared

Comment: $L(t\sin(t))=(t\cos(t)+\sin(t))’=t\sin(t)+2\cos(t)$. So L(third vector of B) is 2[first vector of B]+(-1)[last vector of B]

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, you're right, thanks